# How to add MountSpec component in LayoutSpec or XML in android

Tags: litho, facebook-litho

I am able to set MountSpec directly in Activity setContentView(), but its not working when I am trying to add it with my existing XML view (using LayoutSpec or even directly).

Comment: Hello Welcome to StackOverflow, This question does not provide enough information always try to provide some information related to what you tried so far with some of your code and share where are you stuck. Help people to help you. also have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `LithoView` to connect between Spec and Android native view.

Also Spec can't be used in XML directly.